# poor texture detail on big mesh

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I have a big mesh on which I'm applying a texture. For the texture to show detailed enough, it has to be very big, causing all kinds of obvious problems. I'm thinking of breaking the mesh in sections (let's say 4) so I can make the texture a 4th of its size.
My question is: Is there some trick with applying textures I could use instead? Some way to apply the texture only to the section shown on the view?

I'm using opengl es 2.0 on android.

Appreciate all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

for those having similar problem, This is how I solved it:

.Identified a pattern in my image texture and reduced its size from 2048 to 256
.Multiplied all my texture coordinates by 16, causing coordinates to fall outside the texture boundaries.
.Used texture parameters GL_TEXTURE_WRAP and GL_REPEAT.

This caused the small texture (but with high definition), to be tiled all over the mesh.